# How to single logout in single page website

Tags: wso2

I am building a website that use wso2 as an authorization server. I use angular8 for frontend, and asp.net core for backend. I want implement single logout function. I had read documention, but found it was only solution for frontend, our backend is stateless, how we validate user session of user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to revoke the access token, using the revoke endpoint from oauth2,`/oauth2/revoke` for more about this you can see this documentation
`https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/OAuth2+Token+Revocation`